# Cannot link .so files with header files: Undefined reference to GLEW and freeglut libraries on Linux

Tags: c++, ubuntu, glut, glew, freeglut

I'm working on docker VM and I installed glew and freeglut on my docker image and updated the environment variables to include the .h and .so files by doing so:

```
> export $PATH = /usr/include/GL:

> export $PATH = /usr/lib/:
```

as my main.cpp file uses both libraries.
so when I compile the file by doing so:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

it prints out the following error:

> /tmp/ccZTc4GP.o: In function `main':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x621): undefined reference to`__glewGenBuffers'
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x636): undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x649): undefined reference to`__glewBufferData'
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x676): undefined reference to `__glewBindBufferBase'
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x6f3): undefined reference to`__glewMemoryBarrier'
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x701): undefined reference to `__glewMapBufferRange'
>   /tmp/ccZTc4GP.o: In function`__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x796): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x7a5): undefined reference to`std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
>   /tmp/ccZTc4GP.o:(.eh_frame+0x73): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
>   /tmp/cc5rJijl.o: In function`ParallelMapping::init()':
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `__glewCreateProgram'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to`__glewCreateShader'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `__glewShaderSource'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to`__glewCompileShader'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `__glewGetShaderiv'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to`__glewGetShaderInfoLog'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `__glewAttachShader'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to`__glewLinkProgram'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x13d): undefined reference to `__glewUseProgram'
>   /tmp/cc5rJijl.o: In function`ParallelMapping::compute(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float*, float*, int, int, int)':
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x199): undefined reference to `__glewUseProgram'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x1aa): undefined reference to`__glewUniform1f'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x1bb): undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to`__glewUniform1f'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x1eb): undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x20a): undefined reference to`__glewUniform1f'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x21b): undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x23a): undefined reference to`__glewUniform1f'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x24b): undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x26a): undefined reference to`__glewUniform1f'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x27b): undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x29a): undefined reference to`__glewUniform1f'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x2ab): undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x2ca): undefined reference to`__glewUniform1f'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x2db): undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x2fa): undefined reference to`__glewUniform1fv'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x30f): undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x330): undefined reference to`__glewUniform1fv'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x345): undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x366): undefined reference to`__glewDispatchCompute'
>   /tmp/cc5rJijl.o: In function `ParallelMapping::initGLEW()':
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x392): undefined reference to`glutInitDisplayMode'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x397): undefined reference to `glewInit'
>   /tmp/cc5rJijl.o: In function`ParallelMapping::initGLUT()':
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x3c2): undefined reference to `glutInit'
>   ParallelMapping.cpp:(.text+0x3cc): undefined reference to`glutCreateWindow'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

It knows that the functions are in the header files but it can't reference to the .so files.

What can I do to link both files together?

Comment: You need to read up on link editing. In short, you need to use L to tell the g++ where to look for libraries and use -l to tell it which libraries to link with.

Comment: @PaulFloyd I tried using the following:
g++ -I /usr/include/GL/ -L /usr/lib/  main.cpp

and still got the same error.